# Where can I download an optimized profession list for import into Gnomoria?

Tags: gnomoria

A few patches back the game introduced the ability to import profession settings.

Is there any premade list I can download?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed.  The submitter is not asking for a recommendation of a game.  The game is already picked: it's Gnomoria.  This question is asking for a recommended strategy/loadout for that particular game.

Comment: @Timbo it's a shopping question asking for recommendations of software in a way, and would be a bad fit for the site even if it weren't off-topic. Your suggested edit might get it reopened, but it conflicts with the original intent of the author, and I'd close it as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I understand why "what game should I play?" is a bad question.  I don't understand why "how can I optimize my gameplay using this specific domain within the game; can you point me to a configuration file as a shortcut?" is a bad question.   I strongly believe the second interpretation was NoneOfYourBusiness's intent.  You have to stretch the meaning of 'software' and the intent of 'no software recommendations' pretty far to include configuration data under that umbrella.

Comment: All discussion of strategy is opinion-based given a sufficiently complex system; at the point where an objective answer is possible, are we even talking about a game any more?

Comment: @Timbo I appreciate it you trying to get this reopened, but it wasn't closed bcs its a bad question, it was more or less revenge. But I leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen an optimized list anywhere. The game is also still in a kind of alpha/beta mode. So any optimized list may become useless over the next few months. Especially since the developer is still adding and improving the profession priority system.

I'd say check out http://www.gnomoriawiki.com/wiki/Professions every so often.

And of course the forums will probably have something show up soon. http://forums.gnomoria.com/index.php

Comment: Not really an answer sorry. I know it is still Beta, but the game is accesible for everyone and lists can be updated.

Comment: I would have just commented but I can't yet. Good Luck. I'll keep any eye out myself.

Answer (score -1):

I still find Kelderek's list useful:
http://forums.gnomoria.com/index.php?topic=4597.0

Comment: Please add comments when you mod an answer down to help improve the answer and the site.